# Rails loading fixtures with wrong foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures

I'm writing a simple app using rails 4.1.0. I created two models called Serie and Event, with a one to many relationship between them (as in one Serie has many Events).

```
class Serie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :serie
end
```

I created the following fixture files for these models:

```
#series.yml
---
Serie1:
  name: Whatever

#events.yml      
---
EventSerie11:
  date: 2013-01-01
  value: '124.4'
  serie: Serie1
EventSerie12:
  date: 2013-02-01
  value: '124.2'
  serie: Serie1
```

The problem is that when I load these fixtures by using `rake db:fixtures:load`, I get the wrong foreing keys for the event objects:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
2.1.1 :001 > Serie.first.id
  Serie Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "series".* FROM "series"   ORDER BY "series"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => 10
2.1.1 :002 > Serie.first.events.count
  Serie Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "series".* FROM "series"   ORDER BY "series"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events"  WHERE "events"."serie_id" = ?  [["serie_id", 10]]
 => 0  
2.1.1 :003 > Event.first.serie
  Evento Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events"   ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Serie Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "series".* FROM "series"  WHERE "series"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 627975337]]
 => nil 
2.1.1 :004 > Evento.first.serie_id
  Evento Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "eventos".* FROM "eventos"   ORDER BY "eventos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => 627975337
```

So you see that all fixtures are loading, but the Event records are being assigned an incorrect serie_id foreign key (and since I'm using sqlite for development there are no constraint checks). As far as I can tell, each time I reset the database and load the fixtures, the Serie record gets a new id, but the serie_id field of each Event record is always set to 627975337.

I read [here](http://lovehateubuntu.blogspot.com/2008/09/rails-fixtures-order.html) that you can specify the load order for your fixtures; however adding the line

```
ENV["FIXTURES"] ||= "series,events"
```

to my environment.rb file didn't work, nor did running

```
rake db:fixtures:load FIXTURES=series,events
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think rails is getting in a muddle with your class/fixtures name for `series`. It tries to look for a model class named `Series` because it struggles to singularize your plural name. (Series being a word in english where the plural is the same as the singular).

I strongly suspect that the `Serie` instance in your database is nothing to do with your fixture load at all and is instead an instance that has been created via another method.

The `serie_id` used in your events fixtures is correct. The id that is used is calculated using:

```
> ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:Serie1)
=> 627975337
```

which you can see is the same as the value used in your fixtures.

So, a solution, you can either get into the bowels of active record and override the rake task that loads the fixtures - or you can define your singular/plural versions of "serie"/"series" to be what you want rather than what rails is guessing. In `config/application.rb` or an initializer you can add:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'serie', 'series'
end
```

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Here, have some more reputation.